# Changing a Column's Data Type using Grails db-migration plugin

Tags: postgresql, grails, database-migration

I keep hitting this `MigrationFailedException`

whilst attempting to convert a boolean to integer. I know that at SQL level I could use `USING (col_name::integer)` to instruct Postgresql how to cast. I wonder if there is any syntax that I could use on my changelog script to prevent getting the aforementioned exception.

The version of the plugin I am using is 1.4.0 and I am favouring groovy over XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after some research, there is no way to instruct `modifyDataType` (see [Liquibase's DSL](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html), as Liquibase constitutes the foundations of grails-database-migration plugin) how to perform a type cast on a specified column.

I presume this is because type casting (whenever applicable) has a specific syntax that is DBMS-dependent. Pity.